# Navbar change style on scroll with transition

Tags: jquery, html

I have this:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j(window).on("scroll",function(){
          j('.tm-headerbar').toggleClass('shadow',j(document).scrollTop() > 90);
          j('.tm-headerbar').toggleClass('light',j(document).scrollTop()==0);
        })
```

Works nicely, so far so good... The question is: how can I implement transition during this change of class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

I need to implement `transition` on `.tm-headerbar` class.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4w76/)